# html table border rendering problem on chrome

Tags: html, css

html table border rendering problem on chrome. I hava code like:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#first td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-style: dashed;
}

#second td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="first">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">b</td>
        <td>c1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c3</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table id="second">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">b</td>
        <td>c1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c3</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

On first table, the left border of c2 is looks like a solid line, while I set to td {border-style: dashed;}. I'm troubled.

On second table, why the left border of c2,c3 are darker then c1's on Chrome?

And how to fix them? All the test works fine in Firefox.

Comment: instead of using rgba color use solid color like `border-color: #ddd`

Comment: Insted of using rgba -- border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); ====== use #c1c1c1 code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What i consider is the rendering logic, if I set to td {border-style: dashed;}, the left border of c2 ,c3 is looks like a solid line...

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using `rgba` -- `border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);` ====== use `#c1c1c1` code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    td {
      border: dashed 1px #c1c1c1;
    }
    
    tr {
      height: 80px;
    }
    
    col {
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
      <col />
      <col />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">b</td>
        <td>c1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you，But what i consider is the rendering logic, if I set to td {border-style: dashed;}, the left border of c2 ,c3 is looks like a solid line...

Comment: emmmmm，when the border width of td is 3px，you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use solid color instead of used rgba color

```css
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ddd;
}

tr {
  height: 80px;
}

col {
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  border-color: #ddd;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col />
    <col />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">b</td>
      <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What i consider is the rendering logic, if I set to td {border-style: dashed;}, the left border of c2 ,c3 are looks like a solid line...

Answer (score 0):

it because of you give opacity to border color.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
        td {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #a3a3a3;
        }
        tr {
            height: 80px;
        }
        col {
            width: 200px;
        }
        table {
            border-color: #a3a3a3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <colgroup>
                <col />
                <col />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4">b</td>
                    <td>c1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>c2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>c3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>c4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you，But what i consider is the rendering logic, if I set to td {border-style: dashed;}, the left border of c2 ,c3 is looks like a solid line...